# Java - Apache POI - Import Chart Style from file ".crtx"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a lot of charts
Apache POI seems to don't be as functional as I would like it to be
Each time I need to apply Chart Template to Chart in excel

How to import Chart File ".crtx"?

Comment: Apache POI does not have that functionality. And I doubt it will have in next future, since even the more basically functionalities are not really ready until now. Microsoft develops Microsoft Office since decades, having thousands of employed developers. And the Apache POI project is trying to catch up that with just a handful of volunteers.

Comment: Axel, are there any replacements which allows that? - that would help a lot